# unity library function always returning 0

Tags: c#, function

I have written a library for unity and one function is supposed to return time played. might be easier to explain with the code.

```
public int UNI_TimePlayed(int timePlayed)
        {
            if (timePlayed != 60)
            {
                // division impossible, treat this exception here
                return timePlayed;
            }
            else
            {

                // it's safe to divide
                int timeInMin = timePlayed / 60;
                return timeInMin;
            }
        }
```

if the time played is not equal to 60 seconds then it should return the value. if it is 60 or over then carry out the equation and return the new value.

when I call this in unity, it will only work once my timer goes over 60 seconds, if not then it returns 0., for example, my timer in unity works, I log the value from it before it is inserted into this function. on one occasion the value inserted was 62, the function returned a correct value to me. this occasion the timer was 23 and when this was inserted the function returned 0? as you can see I have tried to get it to just return the value inserted if it is less than 60 but it will not work.

Comment: Why is division impossible? You can always `return timePlayed / 60;` to get time in minutes. If you still want to differentiate then if should be `if (timePlayed < 60)` however, it seems strange to sometimes return times in seconds and sometimes in minutes.

Comment: The else branch - you will only get there is timePlayed is exactly 60.  So the answer will always be 1.  Is this what you intend?

Comment: Could you clarify what your expected values are from this function? I.e., given an input, what output do you expect? Please edit your question to include these examples.

Comment: what I intend is for it to hit the else branch if the time entered is greater than 60 go to the else and if it is less then just return the value entered

Comment: yes so if an input of 120 is inserted into the function then I want it to return 2 which it does. The issue is with if the value is less than 60, I want it to just return whatever value was entered, so if 23 is entered, I want it to return 23 and not 0

Comment: As I already said: `if (timePlayed < 60) return timePlayed; return timePlayed / 60;`. But I would return it as string: `if (timePlayed < 60) return $"{timePlayed} s"; return $"{timePlayed / 60} min";`. Note `!=` is NOT EQUAL, `<` is LESS THAN.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Hi, if I change my code to what you suggested it still returns 0 from the function

Comment: Then `timePlayed` is probably `0`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes my apologies Olivier, I have been wondering why it wasn't working because the code is logically correct. it was the way I was adding this library file to unity itself. I just saved and recompiled the code you suggested and cleanly added it to unity and it is working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `!=` which means "not equal". You should use `<` which means "less than".

```
public int UNI_TimePlayed(int timePlayed)
{
    if (timePlayed < 60) return timePlayed;
    return timePlayed / 60;
}
```

However, a value suddenly changing from seconds to minutes is quite surprising. Returning a string containing the unit would seem more natural.

```
public string UNI_TimePlayed(int timePlayed)
{
    if (timePlayed < 60) return $"{timePlayed} s";
    return $"{timePlayed / 60} min";
}
```